# Solenoid expressions

Tags: forces, inductance

I am wanting an expression for the nearly uniform force (not magnetic force) through the central axis of a solenoid, with a nonmagnetic tube but coiled wires with fixed current, and an explanation of the derivation of it.

I have already tried to find some resources, and have found: http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Magnets/Solenoid-Force-Calculator.phtml

But, in my opinion this is not such a good approximation because it does not incorporate the length of the solenoid. For instance, a lengthy solenoid with same number of coils would have weakened field lines resulting in a weakened force.